# Html5 Mime type error in grails

Tags: html, grails, cache-manifest

I am trying to create a web application using grails 1.3.7 for iPad using a cache manifest to save the data offline. I got offline data working very fine in Chrome but in Safari, iPad and Mozilla it is giving an error saying the Application Cache manifest has an incorrect MIME type: `text/plain`. I have set mime type in `Config.groovy` as follows:

```
grails.mime.types = [ html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
                      xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
                      text: 'text/plain',
                      js: 'text/javascript',
                      rss: 'application/rss+xml',
                      atom: 'application/atom+xml',    
                      css: 'text/css',
                      csv: 'text/csv',
                      all: '*/*',
                      json: ['application/json','text/json'],
                      form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
                      manifest: 'text/cache-manifest' 
                    ]
```

But still the other browsers do not accept it.  I am really confused whether this is a html5 problem or grails.  It works in chrome.

Comment: Have you used the inspector in chrome to confirm the correct MIME type header is being sent?

Comment: yes I have seen in chrome inspector every thing is working fine in chrome........In chrome cache each satuts is displayed

Comment: You already said everything is working fine in Chrome, I'm not asking about the cache status, I was asking if you'd looked at the headers on the response to confirm the correct ones are being sent

Answer (score 2):

Hey I got the solution I found out that mime type was not set in grails....In grails to set the mime type a different way is to be follwed (But still I wonder why chrome was working without mime type)............To set the mime type in grails we have to create a web.xml and add the following code to it...

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>manifest</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

But in grails web.xml is created only at the time when war is build....So to create a web.xml which can be merged with original web.xml do the following

In the command line type

```
grails install-templates
```

Now in your project folder src/templates/war is created. in the war folder create the web.xml and add the code you need... hope this will help

Comment: fyi: the [recommended](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) extension for the manifest file is ".appcache" instead of ".manifest".

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modify the `web.xml` file, you can also simply set the HTTP content type header directly from your controller action via the `HTTPResponse` object:

```
response.contentType = "text/cache-manifest"
```

The `grails.mime.types` block in `Config.groovy` is used during [content negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation) to allow you to more easily send back different responses to a request based on the inbound Accepts header.